# Why is my span's text not changing?

Tags: jquery

When a user clicks on a button, I'm trying to get the child span to fade out, change its text, fade back in, and then revert back to the original text, fading out and in once more:

```
<button id="clickMe">
    <span>Click Me</span>
</button>

$('body').on('click','#clickMe',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $span = $this.find('span');
    var $text = $span.text();
    $span.fadeOut(180)
        .text('Clicked')
        .fadeIn(180)
        .delay(1200)
        .fadeOut(180)
        .text($text)
        .fadeIn(180);
});
```

The button fades at the correct intervals, but the text never changes. No errors. What am I doing wrong?

Proof, if proof be needed: http://jsfiddle.net/verism/XPyHZ/

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help and clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use callback functions do some process after fadeIn or fadeOut.

Otherwise `text("Clicked")` and `text($text)` works immediately.

```
$('body').on('click','#clickMe',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $span = $this.find('span');
    var $text = $span.text();
    $span.fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $(this).text("Clicked");
        })
        .fadeIn(180)
        .delay(1200)
        .fadeOut(180, function() {
            $(this).text($text)
        })
        .fadeIn(180);    
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2aSb5/3)

Answer (score 4):

.text() applies immediately every time - it's not subject to the .delay().
Use the callback parameter of the animation calls to get the correct result:

```
$('body').on('click','#clickMe',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var $span = $this.find('span');
    var $text = $span.text();

    $span.fadeOut(180, function() {
        $span.text('Clicked')
            .fadeIn(180)
            .delay(1200, function() {
                $span.fadeOut(180, function() {
                    $span.text($text)
                        .fadeIn(180);
                });
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Learned a new trick: http://jsfiddle.net/ - which would have been useful before - wrote the above from memory, and evidently got something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`.text()` won't actually wait the delay, only animation functions take delay into account.

So here what happens is that the text change to the new value and goes back to the old one right away. Use the `fade` methods callback to wait the delay.

```
$span.fadeOut(180)
    .text('Clicked')
    .fadeIn(180)
    .delay(1200)
    .fadeOut(180, function() { span.text($text) })
    .fadeIn(180);
```

Comment: Does this code fade out before changing the text the first time?
I had thought that was what he wanted it to do when I wrote my answer.

Comment: I don't know. I was more concerned about the principle of what happened. Your answer is good too.

Comment: This answer lead to me figuring it out; but I've changed the accepted to @ocanal's solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the text changes don't get queued up into the effects queue like the fadeIn/fadeOut functions do.  The text changes and then changes back.  It happens so fast you never see it.  If you set the text in your final text() call to something other than the original text, you'll see that it's changing.

The solution is to work with the callback functions on the fadeIn|Out functions.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling .text() twice, one with 'Clicked' then you reset it to the initial text with .text($text);

http://jsfiddle.net/XPyHZ/3/

```
$('body').on('click','#clickMe',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $span = $this.find('span');
    var $text = $span.text();
    $span.fadeOut(180)
        .text('Clicked')
        .fadeIn(180)
        .delay(1200)
        .fadeOut(180)
        .fadeIn(180);
});
```

Comment: I think OP is just trying to show "clicked" for a while, than changing it to default.

Comment: @ocanal is correct - "and then revert back to the original text".